# Angular 6 input form validation

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 3 input fields which are mainly required but now I want to put the logic that if one of them is filled then the rest of the two should not be required anymore. someway it works correctly but the problem is if I fill the form and then remove the value (so form is basically empty now) it keeps the form valid.

so I type Uname: *abc*
form is valid
but if I remove the Uname --> form is invalid

now on second input if I fill username: *abcdef*
form is **valid**

and now if I remove the username

**form is still VALID**

here is my stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5l9kb4

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way IMHO. None of the fields should have a required validator. Instead, the form group containing them should have a custom validator that triggers an error if none of the 3 fields is filled. All you need is a trivial custom form group validator.

Comment: yes but there is no required validator

Comment: Err, yes, there is. Read your code: every field has `Validators.compose([Validators.required, ...`.

Comment: create custom validator and check each fields value. if any one is not empty it will return false else it will return true to show validation. Read https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-custom-validators-in-angular

Comment: Ah yeah I thought you are taking about html required attribute. but so your suggestion is to have group validation?

Comment: Yes. That's what I said in my comment: *the form group containing them should have a custom validator that triggers an error if none of the 3 fields is filled. All you need is a trivial custom form group validator.*

Comment: makes sense! I understand my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
checkValue() {
this.myForm.get("Uname").valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value  && value.length > 0) {
    this.myForm.controls["username"].clearValidators();
    this.myForm.controls["username"].updateValueAndValidity();
    this.myForm.controls["description"].clearValidators();
    this.myForm.controls["description"].updateValueAndValidity();
  }
});
this.myForm.get("username").valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value  && value.length > 0) {
    this.myForm.controls["description"].clearValidators();
    this.myForm.controls["description"].updateValueAndValidity();
    this.myForm.controls["Uname"].clearValidators();
    this.myForm.controls["Uname"].updateValueAndValidity();
  }
});
this.myForm.get("description").valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value && value.length > 0) {
    this.myForm.controls["username"].clearValidators();
    this.myForm.controls["username"].updateValueAndValidity();
    this.myForm.controls["Uname"].clearValidators();
    this.myForm.controls["Uname"].updateValueAndValidity();
  }
});
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgzz53?file=src/app/app.component.ts) Example.

I have added a simple condition `value.length > 0`  to check minimum length. If you want you can add more validations.
I hope it solves your problems.

Comment: The reason it works only once is because your form is called only once. Your checkValue function is called only once on ngOnInit. You need to write code properly.

Comment: what else could be used instead of ngOnInit? I am stuck there

Answer (score 0):

Your code clears the validators when the value is present. Now when u remove the added value, your code does nothing. You have to add the validators back.

The best way is to add a custom validator to the entire formgroup. This validator will have access to all the controls within the group. Please remove the subscription on each formControl.

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
  Uname : [''],
  username : [''],
  description : ['']

},{ validator: formValidator });

function formValidator(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  const uName = formGroup.controls['Uname'].value;
  const username = formGroup.controls['username'].value;
  const description = formGroup.controls['description'].value;
  return uName === '' && username === '' && description === '' ? { 
  oneFieldRequired: {valid: false} } : null;
}
```

Comment: Please post as a comment or please answer with proper explanation and/or examples.

Answer (score 0):

This should ideally be the responsibility of a `FormGroup` Validator. I'd recommend you to create a Custom Validator that would validate the whole `FormGroup` as that's what you're after anyway:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      uName: [''],
      username: [''],
      description: ['']
    }, { validators: anyOneFieldRequired });
  }

  submit(value) {
    console.log('Form Value: ', value);
  }
}

function anyOneFieldRequired(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  const uName = formGroup.controls['uName'].value;
  const username = formGroup.controls['username'].value;
  const description = formGroup.controls['description'].value;
  return uName === '' && username === '' && description === '' ? { oneFieldRequired: true } : null;
}
```

And in your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm.value)">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="uName">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="username" >
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="description">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgvwsp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: submit button is valid even without filling the form?

Comment: The StackBlitz is not updating with the code that I have here. Can you please check with the code that I posted above?

Comment: @MuhammadAli, please check again. I think you should see it. I've also updated my answer with a Sample StackBlitz.

Answer (score 0):

> first check `onTypeChange($event.target.value)` function

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm.value)">

 <mat-form-field class="full-width">
   value 1
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="Uname" (input)="onTypeChange($event.target.value)">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="full-width">vlaue 2
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="username" (input)="onTypeChange($event.target.value)">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="full-width" >
      value 3
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="description"  (input)="onTypeChange($event.target.value)">
    </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> .ts file

```
 onTypeChange(searchValue : string ) 
     {     
      console.log("typed value"+searchValue);}
      }

 submit(myForm)
  {
        console.log(myForm);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used reactive form validation, but have full fill your requirement.Please check below code : Fiddle Link : [disable form button on condition](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4pd89?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray,
 } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myForm:FormGroup;
  Uname:any;
  username:any;
  description:string;
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  checkForm() {
    console.log(typeof this.Uname,this.username,this.description)
    if((typeof this.Uname !== 'undefined' && this.Uname != '') || (typeof this.username !== 'undefined' && this.username != '') || (typeof this.description !== 'undefined' && this.description != ''))
      return false;
    else 
      return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="Mainform" id="Mainform"  (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm.value)">

 <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput type="text" 
      name="Uname"
      [(ngModel)]="Uname">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput type="text" 
      [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" >
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput type="text" 
      [(ngModel)]="description" name="description">
    </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="checkForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```